# Dijkstras Algorithm implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, dijkstra

I tried Dijkstras algorithm and got confused between 2 implemntation, one keeps track of visited nodes (code1) and other don't keep the track (code2).

Code1:

```
    dis[S] = 0;  //S is source
    vis[S] = 1;
    
    PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    queue.offer(new Node(S, 0));
    
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        
        Node node = queue.poll();
        
        int u = node.v;
        vis[u] = 1;
        
        for(Node n: adj1.get(u)){
            int v = n.v;
            int w = n.w;
            
            if(vis[v] == 0){
                if(dis[u]+w < dis[v]){
                    dis[v] = dis[u]+w;
                   
                }
                 queue.offer(n);
                
            }  
        }
        
    }
    `
```

code2:

```
    dis[S] = 0;
    //vis[S] = 1;
    
    PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
    queue.offer(new Node(S, 0));
    
    while(!queue.isEmpty()){
        
        Node node = queue.poll();
        
        int u = node.v;
        // vis[u] = 1;
        
        for(Node n: adj1.get(u)){
            int v = n.v;
            int w = n.w;
            
            // if(vis[v] == 0){
                if(dis[u]+w < dis[v]){
                    dis[v] = dis[u]+w;
                    queue.offer(n);
                   
                }
                 
                
            // }  
        }
        
    }
```

Code 1 fails some test cases code 2 passes all test cases. can anyone explain why code 1 fails like what are the edge cases i am missing.

Comment: Please add the implementation of `Node.compareTo()`

Comment: Post [mre] please

Answer (score -1):

Both of your implementations are incorrect.  "code 2" might work, but it's probably slow.

The most obvious problem in both implementations is that your priority queue is full of *edges*.  In Dijkstra's algorithm, the queue orders *vertices* by their currently *best discovered cost*.  There is just no way that your priority queue could be doing this properly.

I would guess that you're actually ordering edges by *weight*.  The will give you vertices in the wrong order, which could cause "code 1" to fail because of the visited check.

The next problem is the implementation of the visited check.  If you're not using a heap that supports a `decrease_key()` operation, then you have to add a vertex to the queue every time you decrease the weight, so it could end up in the queue multiple times.  When it comes out of the queue, you will know its best cost, so you can save time by ignoring the other instances in the queue when you see them.

You do *not* use the visited check to ensure that you only add the vertex once, because then keys can't be decreased and your implementation is broken.

A proper implementation looks like this:

```
// initialize dis to max value
for (int i=0; i<dis.length; ++i) {
    dis[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
dis[S] = 0;  //S is source
// Note that S isn't scanned yet, so vis[S] == 0

PriorityQueue<PriorityNode> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
queue.offer(new PriorityNode(S, 0));

while(!queue.isEmpty()){
    
    PriorityNode node = queue.poll(); 
    int u = node.vertex;

    if (vis[u] != 0) {
        // already resolved this vertex
        continue;
    }

    vis[u] = 1;
    
    for(Edge n: adj1.get(u)){
        int v = n.v;
        int w = n.w;
        
        if(dis[u]+w < dis[v]){
            dis[v] = dis[u]+w;
            // We found a better cost for v
            queue.offer(new PriorityNode(v, dis[v]));
        }
    }        
}
```